# GLSL to Metal. Tile

Tags: ios, shader, metal, cikernel

I'm trying to make tile effect from example on shadertoy (https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3llcRN) .
Here is code on GLSL:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = (2.*fragCoord.xy - iResolution.xy)/iResolution.y;    
    fragColor = vec4( texture(iChannel0, uv ).rgba );
}
```

Result:
[image]

Here is my code on Metal:

```
kernel vec4 colorKernel(sampler source, float w, float h)
{
    vec2 d = vec2(w, h);
    vec2 uv = (2.*destCoord().xy - d.xy)/h;
    return vec4( sample(source, uv).rgba );
}
```

And result:

[image]

What is missing? I need same result as on shadertoy

Comment: Can you provide code that shows how you load your image, how you create/apply your filter, and how you display the resulting image? Each of these steps affects the result, owing largely to differences between the default coordinate spaces of UIKit and CoreImage. If all you need is a repeating image, the built-in `CIAffineTile` filter can be used to get that. Even if you need to write a custom kernel, you could chain it with an affine tile filter, since one of the design principles of Core Image is the building up of complex effects from smaller building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when UV's coordinates bigger than 1 it returns just empty color